# Empty DTD Element with extra info

Tags: html, dtd, xml

I know how DTD works and when I want to declare `<br>` (or `<br/>`), I have to do this:

```
<!ELEMENT br EMPTY>
```

But in this file (https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html.dtd), I found the following line:

```
<!ELEMENT BR    - O EMPTY>
```

I see that the most are the same, but what difference does the `-` and the `O` make? Where can I learn more about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-` and `O` (letter O) characters are SGML tag omission indicators, and declare (to an SGML parser) that the start- and/or end-tag, respectively, for an element can be omitted (if `O`) or must be present (if `-`). The first `-` or `O` character is for the start-element tag, and the second is for the end-element tag.

For example, a valid HTML document can look like this (where the "public identifier" is shortened to `...` for clarity):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "...">
<title>A valid HTML document</title>
<p>Body Text
```

SGML uses an HTML DTD (containing element and attribute declarations for HTML) to infer the omitted tags such that the example markup is parsed as

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "...">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A valid HTML document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Body Text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Element declarations with tag omission indicators that would make an SGML parser arrive at the inferred and canonical markup are

```
<!ELEMENT html O O (head,body)>
<!ELEMENT head O O (title)>
<!ELEMENT body O O (#PCDATA,p)+>
<!ELEMENT p - O (#PCDATA)>
```

The case of the `br` element is special because it's an `EMPTY` element (HTML calls these "void elements", and has additional ones such as `img` and`hr`). An element with declared content `EMPTY`, in traditional SGML, isn't allowed to have an end-element tag at all, and use of an end tag omission indicator is redundant or even misleading.

For a full SGML DTD for modern HTML (W3C HTML 5 and 5.1), see my project/paper linked from http://sgmljs.net/blog/blog1701.html .

Note that HTML, since version 5, doesn't anymore publish a SGML DTD or other formal grammar, and doesn't formally reference the SGML standard (ISO 8879) as normative reference. The declaration you stumbled upon is likely from the older HTML 4 specification.

Edit: also wanted to clarify that for using `<br/>` *in XML*, you don't have to declare it `EMPTY`; in fact, you don't have to declare anything at all; also, since you asked for it, you can go to (our site) http://sgmljs.net/docs/sgmlrefman.html for learning more on SGML